# how solve this proplem on models django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, django-models

Finished creating the models file, typed python manage.py  makemigrations main and I get a reply back, 'no installed app with label 'main'.  when I do python manage.py migrate, it says Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.  I even spent considerable time double checking my spelling and it is correct.  Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: share the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: i add that but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

your app.py must look like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MainConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'main'
    verbose_name = 'Some Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your app `main` to the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#installed-apps) in the `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'main'
]
```

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainCnfing',

Comment: @Majd: share the `MainConfig`, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65556404/edit) your question (there is also a "typo" in `MainCnfing` (should be `MainConfig`).

Comment: from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ToDoList(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.name


class Item(modeLs.Model):
 todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 text = models.CharField(max_Length=300)
 complete = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
     return self.text

Comment: @Majd: that is not the app config, but the model... [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65556404/edit) your question...

Comment: yes comment one on setting comment two on models all things true but with error

Comment: @Majd: but you are still not providing the app config... The problem is not in the models, since that file is, based on the error *never loaded*, so very likely a problem in the `MainConfig`...